# How to replace header tokens in all requests with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, token, intercept

The following code snippet updates the header information for each request.

```
   var open: any = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
      open.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
      this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
   };
```

As a result, it merges the header token with the previous request token.

[image]

How can I prevent tokens from merging in the header? In fact, the new token will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**According to the existing document**, rewriting the header in the interceptor is a wrong scenario
This means that the script should not get to the point where the header needs to be rewritten
I suggest checking most of the project to avoid sending unwanted headers

But there is still a way **(non-standard)**
Which somehow overwrited the header
But other problems may arise

```js
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
var method = "";
var url ="";
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (_method,_url) {

method = _method;
url = _url;
open.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments)); 
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
var xml2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml2.open(method, url,true); 
xml2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "aaa");
send.call(xml2, data);
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try first removing the header by

```
this.setRequestHeader("Authorization");
// or
this.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "");
```

and then try re-setting the header.

```
this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
```